# Number of character in the end of a String JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string

I would like to know if anyone know how i can count the name of spaces in the end of a string in JAVA. For example:
// I got this string

```
string = "JAVA CODE   "
```

When I transform it to an array, I will get something like this;

```
arr[0] = J;
arr[1] = A;
arr[2] = V;
arr[3] = A;
arr[4] = ' ';
arr[5] = C;
arr[6] = O;
arr[7] = D;
arr[8] = E;
arr[9] = ' ';
arr[10] = ' ';
arr[11] = ' ';
```

In this case I got three space after the letter E, than, I would like create a method that return only the space after the last character that is not not a space. Any ideas ?

Comment: All spaces are equal, so you can pick any space. Do you mean you want to find the index of the last space after a non-space?

Comment: Consider to use trim() method.. String trim = string.trim(); before you transform it to an array.

Comment: But  trim method, just remove the space and this is not my goal. I would like to know how many characters there in the of this string, do u get it ?

Comment: What is your expected output , What do you need calculate

Comment: `String#charAt(int i)` might be helpful as well as `for-loop`

Answer (score 0):

## Homework recipe

1. Open the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) of `String` class.
2. Navigate to [charAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)).
3. Have a look at method [length](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length())
4. Use your knowledge about `for-loop`. You might be interested in `for (int i = s.XXX - XXX; i >= 0; i--)` - fill `XXX`s on your own.
5. Before the loop initialize counter to 0.
6. Remember about `break` keyword.

Once made, consider replacing in-loop condition so there is no need to use `break`.

## Spoiler-alert!

#### Interesting articles

- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [Minimal Complete Verificable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

#### Sceleton for your code.

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = s.XXX - XXX; i >= 0; i--) {
    //your code here
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
String s = "JAVE CODE   ";
System.out.println(s.length()-s.trim().length());
```

Comment: You count sum of leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @xenteros oh , I will check . Thanks for informing